# Django Static doesn't work on production even after collectstatic

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I'm facing a problem and cannot resolve it. Looking for some advices !

Ok so locally everything works fine, i already run collect static
and i collected statics files under a folder named 'static' on my django app folder :

```
app
|
|- app
|- app n°2
|- static
```

So running locally, not a single error and admin have css
While i push on production, my app run , proxy (nginx) run ...

However, while connectinf to example.com/admin/, css not running

my logs from proxy give me this ...

```
"GET /app/static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://example.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/"
```

An error 404 occur ?

Here is what's my setting.py looks like

```
STATIC_URL = '/app/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/app/static'
```

Any help will be welcome, i would like to understand the error !
Thank a lot

Cheers

---

UPDATE for @ivan

From what i understand here is what's happening :

```
collectstatic -> generate a folder « staticfiles » in django’s app folder -> Dockerfile copy all django’s app -> docker-compose take folder /app/staticfiles and copy in volume static_volume -> docker-compose nginx copy folder /app/staticfiles in her container -> web request : Django's setting try to ask static file on path /static/ -> nginx with alias redirect the /static/ to /app/staticfiles/
```

Here is my current configuration :

Docker-compose (i removed useless info such as certbot and database)

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=${DOMAIN}

  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./docker/proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - proxy-dhparams:/vol/proxy
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
    environment:
      - DOMAIN=${DOMAIN}


volumes:
  proxy-dhparams:
  static_volume:
```

ssl.conf (nginx)

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    ...

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

directory

```
project
|
|app
|-app
|-app n°2
|-staticfiles
|
|Dockerfile
|
|docker-compose.deploy.yml
|
|docker
|-proxy
|--nginx
|---ssl.conf
|-Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile for Django

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"
```

the two kinds of error from my proxy logs :

```
"GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404
```

and

```
"/staticfiles/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I verified if staticfiles folder was in nginx container while running (yes it's there)
[image: nginx container]

Comment: are you serving your static files from nginx? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/

Comment: Oh yes, i am ... location /static { alias /vol/static;} . I may have to remove this ?

Comment: No, that means there might be an issue with your nginx config

Comment: Yes , i should have created a vol in my Dockerfile and move static there, but maybe for a quick fix i can remove this location /static ?

Comment: If it is a docker specific issue, then please share your docker related codes (like docker-compose and Dockerfile)

Comment: Navigate your app container contents and find where your static files a really located. It's not a top-level folder `/staticfiles`, it's `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` or something else dependent on what you have in Dockerfile (how you copy project files into docker image).

Comment: @IvanStarostin , thank you , so i updated my Dockerfile. I should update my volume in my docker-compose to : - static_volume:/app/staticfiles ?

Comment: yes, looks like `/app/staticfiles`. note, in nginx container it will be a virtual folder thus can have any path.

Comment: Thank's @IvanStarostin, i tried and it's resulting in errors, as updated on the question , i still get two kind of error :( , if you want to give your feedback, it will be welcome !

Comment: The whole thing about static files is just a mapping. STATIC_URL -> STATIC_ROOT. nginx location -> file folder. virtual volume -> path in a container. So just check all the configs - do they match with each other? Once again, you can navigate inside your container and find where files are located. Just do this. `/static/css/style.css` vs `STATIC_URL = '/app/static/'` vs `location /static/ {` so `app/static` or just `/static`? `i tried` what exactly? show updated configs.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, thank you for your time and answer. Yes, I try to understand the cycle and path things have to do. I tried to correct based on this. I updated my question with my current configuration and understatement of the problem.

Comment: With shown configs no one should attempt to access `"/staticfiles/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js"`. Both nginx conf and Dockerfile (and I guess docker-compose as well) are reduced and not showing many config options so the problem can be elsewhere. Perhaps nginx is not using the config you think or something is wrong with location. What is shown looks pretty much fine.

Comment: Hi @IvanStarostin, finally avec downing the docker and rebuilt. It's worked ! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You must have these settings in your settings
**settings.py**

```
import os
.
.
.
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Also, put the following configuration in the URL file of the application
**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # admin page url
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    .
    .
    .
    .
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

If you want to serve your files more professionally, it is better to use whitenoise
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/

Comment: Why use whitenoise when the OP using NGINX?

Comment: It’s designed to work nicely with a CDN for high-traffic sites so you don’t have to sacrifice performance to benefit from simplicity.

WhiteNoise works with any WSGI-compatible app but has some special auto-configuration features for Django.

WhiteNoise takes care of best-practices for you, for instance:
    Serving compressed content (gzip and Brotli formats, handling Accept-Encoding and Vary headers correctly)

    Setting far-future cache headers on content which won’t change

Comment: Thank's @AminZayeromali for the info, i didn't know before . But currently i would like to understand my error and finish my work before switching to a new service :) , I updated my answer with more information

Comment: you're welcome. Goodluck